# How to decrypt a crypt's hash?

Tags: php, md5, encryption, crypt

I have this hash generated with crypt function in php:
`$1$jV3.NS/.$JLVMBWe0N/W0Rbft4NgPV`.

I know `$1$` is MD5's hash, `jV3.NS/.` is the salt and the other text is the encrypted string.
Is possible decrypt this hash if I know the salt?

Comment: it's a hash, not an encryption; once you get the value you can't revert it; you can only try to find one of the possible inputs that generated the outputs using huge databases

Comment: Please remember to upvote any answers that helped, and accept the best one.

Answer (score 13):

No. That's the point of a cryptographic hash. It's easy to compute but computationally infeasible to invert.

Comment: +1 for using the words computationally infeasible

Comment: Yeah. Also, sausage UNgrinders can be shown to be computationally infeasible. The proof will be published in a forthcoming article in a peer-reviewed journal. It contains a very interesting corner case which occurs only with merguez sausages.

Answer (score 11):

No. That is the primary purpose for a hash. It is a *one way* mathematical operation.

Answer (score 8):

A hash is a function designed to be easy to run forward, but exceedingly expensive/painful to reverse. Think of it like a sausage grinder. You can put practically anything you want in going forward but it's near impossible to turn the grinder backwards and get the original components back out

Comment: +1 for sausage grinder analogy.

Comment: +1 - though a sausage grinder still produces all of its inputs as output - so it's more of a one-time pad which doesn't preserve its encryption key :) My favourite is say "I'm thinking of two 4-digit numbers. If I multiply them, the final two digits are 12. What two numbers am I thinking of?"

Comment: @PaulDixon I wasn't going for a 100% accurate analogy, more one that shows the level of challenge that would be required in order to piece the parts back together once the "machine" has been run.

Answer (score 0):

No, MD5 and other hashing functions are considered to be one way algorithms to prevent people from doing exactly what you're looking to do. However it IS possible to do a look-up against a library of precompiled words/passwords/etc. And find a match. (commonly called a rainbow table attack).

However the addition of a salt value means you will most likely have to brute force it, which will take a while. Though if you have the setup, there are some GPU accelerated programs that are REALLY fast.

This should get you started.
OphCrack: http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/